# Parameter binding for IN clause with pymssql

Tags: python, sql, parameters, binding, pymssql

I couldnot find this anywhere , so asking it here.

Say I have a query such as

```
SELECT * from TABLE WHERE col in ('a', 'b', 'c', .......);
```

This data is provided by list of strings and it is quite huge with length more than 100. What is efficient way of parameter binding in such scenario.

I am currently doing

```
'SELECT * from TABLE WHERE col in {0}'.format(str(tuple(LIST_OF_DATA)))
```

Another way I could think of is prepare a bind string with length of list such as `','.join(itertools.repeat("%s", len(LIST_OF_DATA)))` and concatenate to query.

Is there any other way other than these to bind with in query a list of data ?

Comment: Don't use string formatting, it's an SQL injection risk. Did you research this?

Comment: I did look into documentation and did search for it. Obviously, I wouldn't go for formatting but couldn't find proper way to do this. I know the second process of preparing the bind data is better but I want to know if there is something better that  I donot know of.